# Wrong report source being shown on crystalreportviewer VB.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm trying to dynamically get my data source from my database using a query but it shows the wrong report source even though the query and data source is correct.

```
Public DA As New SqlDataAdapter
Public DS As DataSet

Public Function executeViaSQL(ByVal sqlquery As String) As DataSet
    DS = New DataSet
    DA = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery, Conn)
    DA.Fill(DS, 0)

    Return DS
End Function

Private Sub formload
     Dim RS As New rptDaily
     DS = New DataSet
     DS = executeViaSQL(query) 'query is public and has a stored query
     RS.Load()
     RS.SetDataSource(DS.Tables(0))
     CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RS
End Sub
```

The report is showing the default report source even though I've set the report source to a dataset from my database.

Additional information, rptDaily.rpt properties:
**Build Action:** Embedded Resource
**Copy to Output Directory:** Do not copy
**Custom Tool:** CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.CodeGen.ReportCodeGenerator
**Custom Namespace:** Blank

I think the problem is the reportsource is pulling data from my database instead of the dataset. But still don't know how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Try  RS.SetDataSource(DS)

Comment: Still showing the same incorrect results

Comment: uncheck "Save data with report" in your report.  Put try/catch block and catch any error  in formload sub.

Comment: Done that already, no error either.